# Can を be left out for this phrase 文句をつける?

Tags: particle-を

In the light novel that I'm reading, the protagonist says

> 「人の趣味に文句つけるなよ！」

After performing the research, I've finally worked out this translation,

> "Don't complain about a person's hobby!"

Unfortunately, it relies on 文句 being a direct object...possibly.  I couldn't find any examples for translating 文句をつける without breaking the phrase apart.

Here are some of the examples that I found when を was included.  (src: http://www.mahou.org/Kanji/3667/?example)

> 彼は何でも僕のすることに文句をつける。 He finds faults with everything I do. [M]
>
> 彼はいつもあれこれと文句をつける。 He is always complaining of this and that.

I'd like to know if the を particle is missing because it's a casual conversation.   Or does the above-listed phrase have a different meaning altogether?

Comment: Your intuit on casual conversation is [discussed here](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14602/is-%E3%82%92-used-in-real-japanese/14609).

Comment: Ah, it looks like this is answered at the very end in one of the answers.  The question was mainly about something slightly different, so I hadn't read it through.  I'm still a bit confused over whether this can happen in story writing but I guess I can make the supposition that if Osaka dialect is sometimes portrayed, why not a realistic everyday conversation?

Comment: If it's authentic to the character, perhaps it's better for the author to forget about the rules.

Comment: The question is why cannot we drop the を in 気をつける ?

Comment: Well, you *can*: [気つけろ](https://www.google.co.jp/search?hl=ja&q=%22%E6%B0%97%E3%81%A4%E3%81%91%E3%82%8D%22)・[気ぃつけろ](https://www.google.co.jp/search?hl=ja&q=%22%E6%B0%97%E3%81%83%E3%81%A4%E3%81%91%E3%82%8D%22)・[気ィつけろ](https://www.google.co.jp/search?hl=ja&q=%22%E6%B0%97%E3%82%A3%E3%81%A4%E3%81%91%E3%82%8D%22) etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That kind of を drops quite often in casual conversation; you say

文句つけるな （文句をつけるな）
文句言うな （文句を言うな）
ケチつけるな（ケチをつけるな）
ケーキ全部食べちゃった。（ケーキを全部食べてしまった。）
うどん買っといて。（うどんを買っておいて。）
宿題やんなさい！（宿題をやりなさい。）